# My Nginx server is not working

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, virtualhost, drupal

I have an Apache server on Ubunu 18.04 with a Drupal 8 site that I want to migrate to Nginx and PHP7.3-FPM.

This is the only site on the server. I do not know Nginx at all. The site works with Apache but it does not work with Nginx.

I deleted Apache with the following command :

```
sudo apt autoremove --purge apache2*
```

Here is the configuration I had on Apache :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerAdmin contact@domaine.com
   ServerName domaine.com
   ServerAlias www.domaine.com
   Protocols h2 http/1.1
   DocumentRoot /var/www/www-domaine-com/web/

   <Directory /var/www/www-domaine-com/web>
      Options +Includes -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
      AllowOverride All
      Require all granted
   </Directory>

   <FilesMatch \.php$>
      SetHandler "proxy:unix:/var/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost/"
   </FilesMatch>

   ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
   CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Here's how I installed Nginx :

```
sudo apt install nginx
sudo ufw allow in "Nginx HTTP"
```

I am testing the IP address of my server and the Nginx page is displayed.

```
sudo unlink /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default
```

Here is my Nginx configuration :

```
sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/www-domaine-com

server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name domaine.com www.domaine.com;

    root   /var/www/www-domaine-com/web;
    index  index.html index.php;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
}
```

I create a symbolic link of my new configuration :

```
sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/www.domaine.com /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/
```

I test my configuration :

```
sudo nginx -t
```

This message is displayed :

```
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
```

Answer (score 1):

Your Drupal 8 installation is redirecting homepage traffic to `/fr`, which then returns the nginx 404.

See the headers:

```
$ curl -I http://s1biose.com/
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx/1.14.0 (Ubuntu)
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Connection: keep-alive
Date: Wed, 27 Feb 2019 06:11:22 GMT
Location: http://s1biose.com/fr
X-Drupal-Route-Normalizer: 1
X-UA-Compatible: IE=edge
Content-language: fr
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-Generator: Drupal 8 (https://www.drupal.org)
X-Drupal-Cache: HIT
```

You should do the following, in order:

1. Check the server's clock. It appears to be several hours wrong.
2. Clear Drupal's cache.
3. Check what content your Drupal homepage is returning.

Comment: I do not understand because Drupal 8 is multi language and on Apache it works very well. I just empty the cache but it does not change anything.

Comment: @fgtr It sounds like your current problem is with Drupal. We have a dedicated site for Drupal questions which may be able to give you more help: [drupal.se]

Comment: Thank you I will ask the question down

Comment: I found the solution and it works ;-) but the IP address does not redirect to the domain. An idea ? https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/recipes/drupal/

Comment: You need to add a default virtual host in nginx which redirects requests to the domain.

Comment: There already was a default virtual host but he (mistakenly) unlinked it, as shown in the question.